# TypeScript add properties to specific union cases

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have this type (simplified):

```js
type T1 = {
  kind: 'a';
  prop: string;
} | {
  kind: 'b';
  prop2: number;
};
```

Now I want to add a property `prop3: boolean` **but only to the case of `kind: 'a'`**, like I written:

```js
type T2 = {
  kind: 'a';
  prop: string;
  prop3: boolean;
} | {
  kind: 'b';
  prop2: number;
};
```

I tried the following:

```js
type T2 = T1 & { prop3: boolean }; // Not works, adds to both `kind: 'a'` and `kind: 'b'`

type T3 = T1 & { kind: 'a'; prop3: boolean } // Adds to `kind: 'a'` properly, but intersects `kind: 'b' & 'a'` for `kind: 'b'`, and thus `kind: never`, and thus the whole case is `never`, so it omits `kind: 'b'` entirely - equals to `{ kind: 'a', prop: string, prop2: string }`
```

I suspect the answer has something to do with the built-in utility types like `Exclude` and `Omit`, but can't find a proper solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you're going to do this sort of thing often and need a utility type for it, you can create your own:

```
type IntersectExtract<T, U, V> = T extends U ? T & V : T
```

This means: intersect `V` with just those members of the union `T` that are assignable to `U`:

```
type T2 = IntersectExtract<T1, { kind: 'a' }, { prop3: boolean; }>

/* type T2 = {
    kind: 'b';
    prop2: number;
} | ({
    kind: 'a';
    prop: string;
} & {
    prop3: boolean;
}) */

declare const t2: T2;
if (t2.kind === "a") {
  t2.prop3 === true // okay
} else {
  t2.prop3 === true // error
  // ~~~~~ <-- prop3 does not exist on type {kind: "b", prop2: number}
}
```

Looks like what you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKClA1gSwHYAmAXFAOQCGpA3BlGAE4D2YJAzsPfgOY0C+UAH1S1chEqQBG1Wg2YAmEngCuAWwkR6fGmlCQoASTzANrCAGNgAUQAeHchYA8MADRQAqq4BqAPiSwoELYQhKzuUAD8-gBkUJ5QJDBoOuDQMHJ+hsb0phY2do7wrijY+MRklFC8RXRMYADMJBKMjAA2EOR4VJXeSQD0AFRQuqnpyOiYmKJlktITNfKKquqaaPxCABTjE1PilDRzsixQ7Jx4PKtQMVuYhw1QTa3tnasAlFD9vUkE5i3k9NBmRh4dhDBSwOQ0HAAMyg62AcgAdFMkIhkAAichot5beEI24o5AcJTQXq9KCMLDkEAXCAtUzCTC4-Gown0YlQUkBehMei0TkAP0FgqgDgAtKL5vUoARGBBQnhGMAAtYcCCgUMUqgdlA0RI0a5DmDlGoNLxVkA)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

[Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) and [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) can help a lot here.

```
type T2 =
    Extract<T1, { kind: 'a' }> & { prop3: boolean } |
    Exclude<T1, { kind: 'a' }>;
```

The first line extracts just the union member that matches `{ kind: 'a' }` and merges the new property into that type.

The second line is the type of all other members of the union that are not being changed. So we can simply take our modified type re-create a union with that type to get the result you want.

T2 now is reported as:

```
{
    kind: 'b';
    prop2: number;
} | ({
    kind: 'a';
    prop: string;
} & {
    prop3: boolean;
})
```

Which simplifies to:

```
{
    kind: 'b';
    prop2: number;
} | {
    kind: 'a';
    prop: string;
    prop3: boolean;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKClA1gSwHYAmAXFAOQCGpA3BlGAE4D2YJAzsPfgOY0C+UAH1S1chEqQBG1Wg2YAmEngCuAWwkR6fGmlCRYcpLUwBRAB4dyAY2AAeeABpU2fMTKUovAHxQAZE9lgAMwkEoyMADYQ5HgeglAA9PFQEOb0VsBQutAUpI7RBFDkBAXAABbQeBAA7nRMkPSgRlBmluFKBBB2cI4ozmJupB6eVAlJ9BAAtJbj5MDQ5FBKeDiMMVU4ZckAbhogZdyZpbNQOKxQAHIA8jB9BTlAA)

Comment: Thanks, but the answer of @jcalz is simpler

Comment: I think the two answers are similar; mine builds a new utility type and uses it, while this one uses existing utility types.  Not sure which is “simpler”...

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If either or both answers help you understand how to tackle problems like this yourself in the future, then that's a win in my book :)